# background image is blown up on mobile device

Tags: image, css, background

I have created a parallax page.
On my desktop everything works great but if I view it on a mobile device the image is blown up so far I can literally count the pixels.

I have no idea what causes this.
Even so I have no idea how to fix this....

I don't even know where to start besides Google.
I found one topic where somebody states that this is a Safari issue.

Anyone?

I can't really create a JSFiddle or something because, like you stated, it's made in WordPress.

However please see the attached images. Maybe somebody can see at least where the problem lies and maybe tell me what causes this (global indication)
Desktop:
[image: Desktop version]

Mobile (iPhone)
[image: iPhone]

Comment: you need to show us some code.

Comment: What have you tired? Where is your code? Can you provide a demo demonstrating the issue?

Comment: you've posted a bunch of PHP from wordpress, I'm not going to set up a wordpress server to try to replicate the problem. You need to put together a minimal test case and post on jbin, jsfiddle pr similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try swapping `background-size:cover` to `background-size:contain`. This will ensure the background image fits both its width and height within the window, but could create some blank space. With 'cover', the whole area is guaranteed to be filled, but the image might not be entirely contained which seems to be what's happening now.

Comment: This is exactly what happend. The problem I have now it that there is, like you said, a lot of whit space. But now I know where to start looking. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that the background is just behind the viewport?. That would mean that the image won't scale...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

to head of your HTML?
Or if that is not enough, try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It tells the mobile browser to use device width and to use full initial zoom level.

Comment: Currently set to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`