# Background image enlarged on mobile devices

Tags: image, css, background, background-image

I'm working on my portfolio, and I've set it up so that I have some background images.  It looks great on all the computers that I've tested it on, but the pictures get blown up until all I see are pixels on mobile devices like iPhone and iPad (haven't been able to test other devices yet, but I did test on both chrome and safari). It also looks fine when I do the mobile view on chrome.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203859/background-image-is-blown-up-on-mobile-device) that seems to be the closest thing to my problem, but the solutions don't help me. I can change `background-size` to `contain`, as the top responder says, but I get those white bars on the sides and that's not what I want.

I can't do anything like inspect element on my mobile device, so how do I figure out what the problem is here?

Here's my site: [www.julianbossiere.com](http://www.julianbossiere.com/)

And here's the CSS I'm using for the banner images:

```
#banner-about {
    background-image: url(../img/desktop.jpg);
}

#banner-contact {
    background-image: url(../img/sunset.jpg);
}

#banner-about, #banner-contact {
    height: 60vh;
}

#banner-about, #banner-contact, #image-home {
    transition: height 0.8s;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

#image-home {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../img/julian-rooftop.jpg);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Btw, site looks great!

Comment: @KalpeshSingh That's weird.  But maybe that just means it's not something to worry about...?  Thanks for checking it out, though!